# What does the syntax $\min_{1\leq n \leq N}$ mean in $\min_{1\leq n \leq N} y_n(\mathbf w^{*T}\mathbf x_n)$?

Tags: machine-learning, notation

I'm working through a machine learning problem and it uses the following syntax:

$$\rho=\min_{1\leq n \leq N} y_n(\mathbf w^{*T}\mathbf x_n)$$

I am not familiar with the syntax $\min_{1\leq n \leq N}$. What does that mean?

For reference, this is the full problem:

[image]

Comment: It's a common shortcut for the more formal $$\min\{f(n)\mid n\in\mathcal A\} = \min_{n\in\mathcal{A}}f(n)$$ where "$1\le n\le N$" is intended to mean $n\in\{1,2,\ldots, N\}.$ Although the appearance of two apparent variables "$n$" and "$N$" is a potential ambiguity, the absence of "$N$" in the expression for $f(n) = y_n\left(\mathbf{w}^{*T}\mathbf{x}_n\right)$ makes the meaning clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the long subscript followed by a lowercase letter.

$1 \leq n \leq N$ is all part of the subscript. It means to pick the minimum of any value $y_n(\boldsymbol{w}^{*\,T}\boldsymbol{x}_n)$ where $n$ is between $1$ and $N$.

Comment: That was indeed it. It wasn't until someone edited my original post that I realized that it wasn't $min_1$ by itself. That makes much more sense. Thank you! (I'll mark this correct as soon as the minimum time has lapsed)

Comment: Just to clarify it would be the minimum value of $y_n(w^{*T}x_n)$ correct? The $y_n$ would be included? Edit: Now that I just finished the problem I would assume yes hahaha

Comment: @Grant Yes, that's correct, thanks for improving the answer!